# SQL Server Login failed for user ‘NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON’

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I've been getting this error on my SQL Server 2008 error log every minute, the client IP is the server ip address. It seems the server is trying to connect to the server itself with the anonymous logon? I'm lost I don't get what is going on. Thanks a lot for any advice

Message

> Login failed for user ‘NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON’. Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. [CLIENT

Comment: Check this: https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH204324.html

Comment: Thanks, The article says "This issue is a minor configurational issue with IIS 7.5. No functionality loss is expected." but I'm not running a web server. any other idea? thanks

Comment: That article also suggests to enable anonymous logon in IIS which NOT a solution in my mind if you've got a web app that uses windows authentication for a reason.